# Make Zopim ding agent without opening chat screen

Tags: javascript, livechat, zopim

I'm hoping someone knows a clever way to use the Zopim Javascript API to make the  agent screen 'ding' when a user does something. In this case I'm adding tags when a user performs an action (such as pops up a signup form) but I'd like to alert the agents that this has happened audibly too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zopim API for this simulating the user "saying" something. Implement this code on every element you want to trigger a "ding":

```
<script> 

$zopim(function() { 
$zopim.livechat.say('Visiting popup');
$zopim.livechat.theme.reload(); // apply new theme settings }); 

</script>
```

You can test some more here:
http://modernminds.nl/zopim-configuration-customize-api/

Comment: I'm after a ding that the client doesn't notice / see. In other words I want it to alert me audibly when the client has done something interesting, such as click on some kind of button etc. So I can then initiate a chat with them, or provide some kind of contextual ideas.

Comment: In that case, you can use the trigger activation sound in "Settings > Personal > Sound notifications". Triggers can be anything like visiting a page, clicking on something and.. if there are no trigger options, you can always add a trigger for a tag and create the tag using $zopim.livechat.addTags :)